# Implementing Publish Subscribe Using JMS Spring ActiveMQ

Tags: spring

I want to know how to define Topoic,COnnectionfactory,session in  the configuration file(in XML File) that has to be done for implementing Publish Subscribe(Using Topic) in JMS Spring ActiveMQ?

Please find the below link for detailed explanation.

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=101397

Please help on this..
Regards
Srini

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.

The destination-type was not given before.Hence it has taken the default as Queue.

Regards
Srini